# Executar função quando clicar em "textarea"

Tags: javascript

Como executar uma função quando um `<textarea>` for clicado?

Comment: Estou criando um chat, a parte de enviar, responder a mensagem da pessoa, já está tudo pronto, ficou um código muito grande, ai é complicado eu postar aqui

Comment: Você não precisa postar todo o código, apenas os trechos relevantes ao seu problema. [Essa página](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) tem uma descrição melhor de como construir o seu exemplo.

Answer (score 6):

Para detectar se um campo de texto (`textarea`) foi clicado, com JavaScript *puro* e *unobtrusivo*, você pode fazer:

**HTML:**

```
<textarea id="message"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function $(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

$('message').addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('You clicked on textarea.');
});
```

Para visualizar uma demonstração, [clique aqui (jsFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/N23sM/).

Lembrando que, para eventos ***[unobtrusivos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)***, uma boa prática é através de **[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)**.

Caso queira uma opção em **jQuery**, aí vai:

```
$('#message').on('click', function() {
    alert('Hello!');
});
```

*Ressaltando que o HTML **pode ser o mesmo**.*

Comment: É bom ressaltar que este bind de evento javascript precisa ser chamado somente no **document.ready**, final da pagina ou no **window.load**